# dynamically created marker in Polymer 1.0 / leaflet-map does not render in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, leaflet, element, polymer-1.0

I am trying to add a marker to a specific point on a button click event, on a map using Polymer 1.0 and the leaflet-map web component - [github link](https://github.com/leaflet-extras/leaflet-map).  My code works as expected in Chrome, but in Firefox 41.0.1 I get an error :

> "TypeError : t is null"

(referencing leaflet.js page), and the marker does not display.

Here is the Javascript, in the button's registration:

```
var parent = document.getElementById('nycmap');
nycmap.setToPoint(locator.latitude, locator.longitude);

var newMarker = document.createElement('leaflet-marker');

var lat1 = locator.latitude;
var long1 = locator.longitude;

var lat = document.createAttribute("latitude");       
lat.value = lat1; 
var longi = document.createAttribute("longitude");       
longi.value = long1; 
newMarker.setAttributeNode(lat);
newMarker.setAttributeNode(longi);
newMarker.id="marker";

Polymer.dom(parent).appendChild(newMarker);
```

I also get these warning in Firefox, but I don't think these are the source of this problem:

```
Use of document.createAttribute() is deprecated. Use element.setAttribute() instead.
Use of setAttributeNode() is deprecated. Use setAttribute() instead.
```

(I do not understand how to use `element.setAttribute` to create an element, but this is another question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing things up. Using `setAttribute` is more than enough for what you're trying to do. You need to call it on the element you've just created by using `document.createElement`.If you want this HTML:

```
<leaflet-marker id="marker" latitude="0" longitude="0"></leaflet-marker>
```

You'll need to create one element and add three attributes to it:

```
var marker = document.createElement('leaflet-marker')

marker.setAttribute('id', 'marker')
marker.setAttribute('latitude', locator.latitude)
marker.setAttribute('longitude', locator.longitude)

Polymer.dom(parent).appendChild(marker)
```

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute

Comment: that worked, thanks! one note--I also want to toggle the marker off as well--to do that I needed to add marker.id="marker" to your code above, then remove on a click using var marker = document.getElementById('marker'); marker.parentNode.removeChild(marker);

Comment: ps-the line that threw me is "marker.setAttribute('id', 'attribute')".  I am not exactly sure what is happening there?

Comment: no thanks, always welcome. that line was my bad, edited now.

Comment: ok got it, I edited and now I don't need 'marker.id="marker" .